# Why can't I install Steam?

Tags: software-installation, steam

Whenever I try to install steam on the Terminal, it replies:
`E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`
What's happening? Is there a way to fix it?
If it matters, I have installed Elementary OS Freya.

Answer (score 1):

First try rebooting and if that does not work try running

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Now try to install Steam (remember to use `sudo`)

Answer (score 1):

This happens whenever you try to work with packages in one process (i.e. application), but some other application is already working with packages (as you can see in error message "`...is another process using it?`"). Maybe updates are installing while you were trying to install Steam, or Software Center was opened and something was downloading. When you encounter this, try to close all other package-managing applications, and if that doesn't help, do what Suici said.

Comment: Yes, it might be updates